# Переопределить выдачу токена в rest_framework_simplejwt

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

В стандартом варианте получения токена необходимо вводить username и password :

```
http post http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ username=vitor password=123
```

Можно ли переопределить поведение выдачи токена по другим параметрам модели user, например email и code_confrim :

```
http post http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ email=_some_email_ code=_some_code_
```

Comment: наверное, сначала нужно переопределить модель user

Comment: да,  это ясно, но как потом переопределить выдачу токена?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157056/how-can-i-use-email-in-django-rest-framework-simplejwt-instead-of-username не ваш случай?

Comment: очень похоже, спасибо,  сейчас посмотрю